# standardized residuals in r package fgarch

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using the fGARCH package in R in order to fit an ARMA_GARCH(1,1) model to a time series. I want to extract standardized residuals, meaning the residuals divided by the corresponding daily volatility estimate. I tried to things

```
res <- residuals(m1, standardize=FALSE)
vol <- volatility(m1)
stand.res <- res/vol
```

and

```
stand.res <- residuals(m1, standardize=TRUE)
```

if I plot both results, they differ from each other. Why is that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried some models and both results were the same. Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem; please consider:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(fGarch)
set.seed(4)
x <- runif(6587, -0.10, 0.10)
gfit <- garchFit(formula = ~ garch(2,2), cond.dist = "std", data = x, include.shape=TRUE, trace=FALSE)
```

and

```
condVar = gfit@h.t
resid <- (x / sqrt(condVar)); 
tail(resid) # Standardized Residuals
#[1] -0.4201041 -0.8342208  1.5639541  1.0237848 -0.1779349 -0.7820030

#or

tail(x/ gfit@sigma.t)
#[1] -0.4201041 -0.8342208  1.5639541  1.0237848 -0.1779349 -0.7820030
```

vs

```
tail(residuals(gfit, standardize = TRUE))
#[1] -0.4156200 -0.8297368  1.5684382  1.0282689 -0.1734509 -0.7775190
```